# Adding data that start with common string

Tags: awk, grep

Hi I am trying organize a data set I have. I would appreciate for a help! My data looks something like this:

```
>abc1_1
apple
orange
>abc1_2
grape
melon
>abc2_4
tomato
celery
>abc2_5
carrot
cabbage
```

I would like to add up all the data that has title with same first 4 letters (ie add >abc1_1 and >abc1_2 and title it >abc1) so it would look like this:

```
>abc1
apple
orange
grape
melon
>abc2
tomato
celery
carrot
cabbage
```

Please help me!

Comment: How should your output look like? What have you tried?

Comment: Wow, I'd never have guessed when you said "add up all the data" that THAT is the output you were looking for! It looks like you mean aggregate. Modify your input to add kiwi to both abc1_1 and abc1_2 input and the abc1 output so we can see how you want duplicates handled.

Comment: Just a thought, after seeing the answers: Sometimes you have to just bite the bullet and write a 'true' program using Python or Perl. Most likely it will be more manageable/maintainable in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This MAY be what you want, depending on how you want duplicates handled:

```
$ awk -F_ '/^>/{key=$1; next} {data[key] = data[key] ORS $0} END{for (key in data) print key data[key]}' file
>abc1
apple
orange
grape
melon
>abc2
tomato
celery
carrot
cabbage
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your files are in the same directory this tcsh shell script:

```
foreach file ( `ls * | perl -pe 's/(....).*/$1/' | sort -u` )
   cat ${file}* > ${file}
end
```

Comment: If you don't want duplicates in your file you could just do sort -u after the cat.

Comment: Never write scripts in [t]csh. Google `csh why not`. I'm actually not sure how this answer relates to the question anyway though. Maybe you intended to answer a different question?

Comment: I was answering this question. It will produce the desired output.Csh is not a good idea for longer complex scripts. Everyone agrees on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
sed -r 's/>(....).*/>\1/' | xargs | sed 's/ >/\n>/g' | sort | awk '$1==prev{$1="";print;next}$1!=prev{prev=$1}1' | xargs -n1
```